# MySQL Backup and Recover

Tags: backup, innodb, mysql

I have been running mysqldump on my set of MySQL databases (MyISAM and INNDOB).
Recently I wanted to restore the databases to another server, and so I created the databases and imported the dump file.  It was then that I rezlied that the IBD files were not created.

I was under the impressions that what I was doing was a backup, but in the case of INNODB it seems I have to do a backup of /var/lib/mysql/*/*.ibd as well -- right?

If that's the case, then what is the point of a dumpfile if I have to take a backup of IBD files as well?

I am sure I am missing the obvious...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be wrong, but I think the usage of .IBD files depend on InnoDB settings&version. They are needed in newer InnoDB innstallations in addition of ibdata file.

If you have dumps you do not need either.

Comment: The .ibd files are not _needed_ in any version of mysql/innodb i know of. It's a matter of configuration if innodb stores data per table in .idb-files (which doesn't mean the 'global' ibdata isn't used / is obsolete) or not.

Answer (score 2):

The .ibd files your a talking about are only used/generated for all tables you generate after setting `innodb_file_per_table = 1` in your mysqld's configuration. Otherwise all InnoDB table's stuff will be stored in the global `ibdata*` file.

So i guess, the server you did your restore on, was not using `innodb_file_per_table`, which per se is no problem ...

Answer (score 1):

mysqldump is sufficient. there are other tools like [innodb hot copy](http://www.innodb.com/wp/products/hot-backup/order/) or [xtrabackup](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtrabackup/) that can make backup based on ibd files... but they are alternative solution to regular mysql dump.